# Which is a better performance approach in Tableau?

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard which contains 12 sheets. Currently all of them using the same extract as data source. (size: 60k) Although 11 sheets from the above would only requires a datasource with the size of 12k.

Which the better approach using one datasource (60k) for all the sheets or
using 2 data sources (1st: 12k for 11 sheets and 2nd: 60k for 1 sheet)?

not sure how the tableau server handles this. load the extract once and use it everywhere or load it 12 times? which approach is recommended?

thanks in advance

Comment: using Tableau 10.1.4, not sure if it matters.

Comment: Tableau caches data and fuses similar queries where possible. So if your reports hit the same data source at the same level of detail, then use a single one. If you are working at multiple levels of detail, things get a bit trickier. I'd focus on what makes the most logical sense, and use the performance recorder to look at times, SQL etc to tune when necessary.

Comment: Additionally to what @AlexBlakemore said, the performance gain of condensing a 60k tde to a 12k tde would in most cases not even be noticeable by a normal user. With that kind of data it is certainly easier in terms of administration and maintenance to just have one source at the lowest level of detail and trade-off the view milliseconds you would gain by creating a second source.

Comment: You may want to consider reading The Tableau Performance Checklist blog series by Interworks (https://www.interworks.com/blog/bfair/2015/02/23/tableau-performance-checklist). 12 worksheets on one dashboard can be a performance hit. You can also use performance monitoring within Desktop to see which of the options you presented has the most impact.